# Enable jhipster project cache

Tags: jhipster

I have created a j-hipster project without cache support. Now I want to enable cache for the that project.

How it could be done ? or is it possible to enable it after we create project.

Answer (score 0):

You can add cache support after creating the project by adding `"cacheProvider": "<CacheYouWant>"` in your `.yo-rc.json` and generate the project again with `jhipster --force`. You can also enable the Hibernate cache by adding `"enableHibernateCache": <boolean>` (it is disabled if you choose Memcached).

Check out here to have more information about cache systems in JHipster 
https://www.jhipster.tech/using-cache/